# No. of functions from A to B for which 3 pre-image in A

Tags: combinatorics

If $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, then determine the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ for which exactly $3$ elements in $B$ have their pre-image in A.

$\underline{\bf{My \; Try}}$: Here exactly $3$ elements in $B$ which have their pre-image in $A$ . So first we will select $3$

elements from $7$ elements. which can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{7}{3}$ ways.

Now I could not proceed further. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the phrase "have their pre-image in $A$"? Do you just mean that their preimage is non-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We continue the analysis you started. Take one of the $\binom{7}{3}$  choices. For concreteness suppose it happened to be $\{1,2,3\}$.

We ask how many functions there are from our $5$-element set such that the image of the function is all of $\{1,2,3\}$. We will give a "nice" way of counting this, and then remark about another way.  The first way uses Inclusion/Exclusion.

There are $3^5$ functions from our $5$ element set to $\{1,2,3\}$. However, not all these functions are onto. There are $2^{5}$ functions from our $5$-element set to the set $\{1,2\}$, and $2^5$ to the set $\{2,3\}$, and $2^5$ to the set $\{1,3\}$.
However, if we add these three numbers, we will be overcounting once the function that is always $1$, also the function which is always $2$, also the function which is always $3$. It follows that the number of functions **onto** $\{1,2,3\}$ is
$$3^5-3\cdot 2^5+3.$$
Finally, multiply by $\binom{7}{3}$.

**Remarks:** For more, read about Stirling Numbers of the Second kind.

We could count the number of onto functions by dividing into cases. There are two possibilities: (i) One of $1,2,3$ is the image of $3$ members of $A$, and the other two are the each the image of $1$ member of $A$ or (ii) Two of $1,2,3$ are the image of $2$ elements of $A$, and one is the image of one element.

For (i), **which** of $1,2,3$ is the image of $3$ objects can be chosen in $3$ ways. For each way, **which** $3$ objects are mapped to one can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. Now take the smallest remaining of $1,2,3$. Thee are $2$ ways to choose who will be mapped to it, for a total of $(3)\binom{5}{3}(2)$.

We leave counting functions of type (ii) to you. I get  $90$.

Comment: Thanks André Nicolas got it . can we use inclusion - exclusion principle for functions there are from our 5-element set such that the image of the function 
is all of ${1,2,3}$

Comment: I forgot, was going to mention that I was using inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Thanks André Nicolas got it.

Comment: You are welcome. The "grungy" way mentioned in the remark also works quickly. But it would not be much fun if $A$ had $12$ elements.